# How to paginate Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade, laravel-6

[image]

Hi, I am trying to paginate all these elements, but whatever I tried it shows all on one page, it doesnt split this on more pages.

````
public function referralTransactions($id){
        $user_id=$id;
        $refs=User::where('sponsor_id', '=', $user_id)->pluck('id');
        $alltxns=[];
        $i=0;
        //$m=0;
        if(count($refs)>0) {
            foreach ($refs as $key =>$referral) {

                $alltxn = $this->buyselltransactionlist($referral);
                //$paginate = $this->getpaginateforbuysell($referral, 5);
                //$m=$m+count($alltxn);
                $alltxns[$i]=$alltxn;

                $i++;

            }
        }
        dd($alltxns);
        return view('adminpartials.referral_transactions',
            ['user_id'=>$user_id,
               // 'lists'=>$lists
                'alltxns'=>$alltxns,
                //'referrals'=>$referrals,
                'refs'=>$refs,     
            ]
        );```
````

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a `Collection` macro.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Then you use like any other collection helper.

```
collect([...])->paginate(15);
```

Ref:
https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

Answer (score 2):

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}

$items = $this->paginate($collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

in controller use paginate(number you want perPage),
example :

#Controller

```
$posts=Post::latest()->paginate(number you want)
return view('index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

in View
#loop items

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```